# Common lisp best practices for splitting code between files

Tags: compilation, lisp, common-lisp

I'm moderately new to common lisp, but have extended experience with other 'separate compilation' languages (think C/C++/FORTRAN and such)

I know how to do an ASDF system definition. I know how to separate stuff in packages. I'm using SBCL, by the way.

The question is this: what's the best practice for splitting code (large packages) between .lisp files? I mean, in C there are include files, while lisp lives with the current image state. So with multiple files I need to handle dependencies or serial order in the system definition. But without something like forward declarations it's painful.

Simple example on what I want to do: I have, for example, two defstructs that are part of the same bigger data structure (like struct1 is a parent of some set of struct2). Some functions works on one, some other works on the other and some other use both.

So I would have: a packages.lisp, a fun1.lisp (with the first defstruct and related functions), a fun2.lisp (with the other defstruct and functions) and a funmix.lisp (with functions that use both). In an ideal world everything is sealed and compiling these in this order would be fine. As most of you know, this in practice almost never happen.

If I need to use struct2 functions from the struct1 ones I would need to either reorder or add a dependency. But then if there's some kind of back call (that can't be done with a closure) I would have struct1.lisp depending on struct2.lisp and vice-versa which is obviously not valid. So what? I could break the loop putting the defstruct in a separate file (say, structs.lisp) but what if either of the struct's function need to access the common functions in the third file? I would like to avoid style notes.

What's the common way to solve this, i.e. keeping loosely related code in the same file but still be able to interface to other ones. Is the correct solution to seal everything in a compilation unit (a single file)? use a package for every file with exports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lisp dependencies are simple, because in many cases, a Lisp implementation doesn't need to process the definition of something in order to compile its use.

Some exceptions to the rule are:

1. Macros: macros must be loaded in order to be expanded. There is a compile-time dependency between a file which uses macro and the file which defines them.
2. Packages: a package `foo` must be defined in order to use symbols like `foo:bar` or `foo::priv`. If `foo` is defined by a `defpackage` form in some `foo.lisp` file, then that file has to be loaded (either in source or compiled form).
3. Constants: constants defined with `defconstant` should be seen before their use. Similar remarks apply to inline functions, compiler macros.
4. Any custom things in a "domain specific language" which enforces definition before use. E.g. if Whizbang Inference Engine needs rules to be defined when uses of the rules are compiled, you have to arrange for that.
5. For certain diagnostics to be suppressed like calls to undefined functions, the defining and using files must be taken to be as a single compilation unit. (See below.)

All the above remarks also have implications for incremental recompilation.
When there is dependency like the above between files so that one is a prerequisite of the other, when the prerequisite is touched, the dependent one must be recompiled.

How to split code into files is going to be influenced by all the usual things: cohesion, coupling and what have you. Common-Lisp-specific reasons to keep certain things together in one file is inlining.  The call to a function which is in the same file as the caller may be inlined.  If your program supports any in-service upgrade, the granularity of code loading is individual files. If some functions `foo` and `bar` should be independently redefinable, don't put them in the same file.

Now about compilation units. Suppose you have a file `foo.lisp` which defines a function called `foo` and `bar.lisp` which calls `(foo)`.  If you just compile `bar.lisp`, you will likely get a warning that an undefined function `foo` has been called. You could compile `foo.lisp` first and then `load` it, and then compile `bar.lisp`. But that will not work if there is a circular reference between the two: say `foo.lisp` also calls `(bar)` which `bar.lisp` defines.

In Common Lisp, you can defer such warnings to the end of a compilation unit, and what defines a compilation unit isn't a single file, but a dynamic scope established by a macro called `with-compilation-unit`. Simply put, if we do this:

```
  (with-compilation-unit
    (compile-file "foo.lisp")  ;; contains (defun foo () (bar))
    (compile-file "bar.lisp")) ;; contains (defun bar () (foo))
```

If a `compile-file` isn't surrounded by `with-compilation-unit` then there is a compilation unit spanning that file. Otherwise, the outermost nesting of the `with-compilation-unit` macro determines the scope of what is in the compilation unit.

Warnings about undefined functions (and such) are deferred to the end of the compilation unit. So by putting `foo.lisp` and `bar.lisp` compilation into one unit, we suppress the warnings about either `foo` or `bar` not being defined and we can compile the two in any order.

Build systems use `with-compilation-unit` under the hood, as appropriate.

The compilation unit isn't about dependencies but diagnostics. Above, we don't have a compile time dependency. If we touch `foo.lisp`, `bar.lisp` doesn't have to be recompiled or vice versa.

By and large, Lisp codebases don't have a lot of hard dependencies among the files. Incremental compilation often means that just the affected files that were changed have to be recompiled. The C or C++ problem that everything has to be rebuilt because a core header file was touched is essentially nonexistent.

Answer (score 2):

> but what if

No matter how you first organize your code, if you change it significantly you are going to have to refactor. IMO there is no ideal way of grouping dependencies in advance.

As a rule of thumb it is generally safe to define generic functions first, then types, then actual methods, for example. For non-generic functions, you can cut circular dependencies by adding forward declarations:

```
(declaim (ftype function ...))
```

Having too much circular dependency is a bit of a code smell.

> Is the correct solution to seal everything in a compilation unit

Yes, if you group the definitions in the same compilation unit (the same file), the file compiler will be able to silence the style notes until it reaches the end of file: at this point it knows if there are still missing references or if all the cross-references are resolved.

> But then if there's some kind of back call (that can't be done with a closure)

If you have a specific example in mind please share, but typically you can define `struct1` and its functions in a way that can be self-contained; maybe it can accept a map that binds event names to callbacks:

```
(make-struct-1 :callbacks (list :on-empty one-is-empty
                                :on-full one-is-full))
```

Similarly, `struct2` can accept callbacks too (Dependency Injection) and the main struct ties them using closures (?).

Alternatively, you can design your data-structures so that they `signal` conditions, and the in the caller code you intercept them to bind things together.

Comment: Yes, I knew about the declaim type but it seemed a little low level to use. Since these structs are closely related I think the best way would be to seal everything in a compilation unit. Thanks for the advice